# custom header overlaps cells in group

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

Im a bit stuck trying to create a custom ios table header. My headers are 30px tall and I am using this code to create them:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    if (sectionTitle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init] ;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 30);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_gradient.png"]];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    label.text = sectionTitle;

    // Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 30)];
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewheightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}
```

It almost works, but my headers seem to colide with the cells/headers below them:

[image: custom headers]

Can anyone point me in the right direction on cleaning up the headers here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing a [space]:

You have:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewheightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

It should be:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

Comment: It should actually be `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: Correct. The correct declaration is as follows (from the docs): - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section - if you're paying close attention, there's a [space] missing between tableView and heightForHeaderInSection... Totally missed that the first time around, hence why I assumed the camel case was off. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: thanks for the help... I was going crazy trying to figure out why that wasn't working!